# How can I only have one item highlighted?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view of labels and you can select a label. Currently you can select as many as you like, but I want to limit that to only one. Only one label can be selected. If you select one label and click on another one the previous label will go back to the original color and the newly selected one will change colors.

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: celltell = tc.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! celltell

        cell.t.text = av[indexPath.item]
        cell.t.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        cell.t.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor
        cell.t.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        cell.t.tag = indexPath.row

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tme:")
        cell.t.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        cell.t.userInteractionEnabled = true

    return cell
}

 func tme(gest: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    let label: UILabel = gest.view as! UILabel
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    checker = label.tag

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
take gloable variable at top of viewDidLoad
Var selectedIndex : Int  

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: celltell = tc.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! celltell

        cell.t.text = av[indexPath.item]
        cell.t.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        cell.t.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor
        cell.t.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        cell.t.tag = indexPath.row
        if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex){
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor
           label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        }
        else{
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor
           label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tme:")
        cell.t.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        cell.t.userInteractionEnabled = true

    return cell
}

 func tme(gest: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    let label: UILabel = gest.view as! UILabel
    selectedIndex = label.tag
    self.collectionView.reloadData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set highlighted color for label.